# Use stored procedure in values of an Insert statement

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, reactjs

I'm trying to use a stored procedure in an insert statement this is my code:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @statement=N'insert into Celulares_Empleados(CEL_IMEI,Empl_ID,FH_Asignacion,US_Asigno) 
values (@imei, EXEC EMPLEADOS_LEGAJOS @legajo, @date, @usuario)',
@params=N'@imei nvarchar(15), @legajo nvarchar(41), @date datetime, @usuario nvarchar(5)',
@imei=N'353108089985778',
@legajo=N'USUARIO DE PRUEBA - Legajo: 1171',
@date='2020-06-18 22:56:08.367',
@usuario=N'admin'
```

But I get this message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I also tried to put the `Exec` statement between ( ) but I get the same error.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can't execute a stored procedure as part of a values statement.

Comment: This is the best you can do https://www.tutorialgateway.org/insert-stored-procedure-result-into-temporary-table-in-sql/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call stored procedure as part of VALUES clause in INSERT. What you can do is, first execute the stored procedure and get the return value in a variable. Use the variable as part of your sp_executesql procedure call.

```sql
DECLARE @p_Empl_ID int
DECLARE @legajo NVARCHAR(41)= N'USUARIO DE PRUEBA - Legajo: 1171'
EXEC @p_Empl_ID = EXEC EMPLEADOS_LEGAJOS @legajo

EXEC sp_executesql @statement=N'insert into Celulares_Empleados(CEL_IMEI,Empl_ID,FH_Asignacion,US_Asigno) 
values (@imei,@Empl_ID , @date, @usuario)',
@params=N'@imei nvarchar(15), @legajo nvarchar(41), @date datetime, @usuario nvarchar(5)',
@imei=N'353108089985778',
@Empl_ID = @p_Empl_ID ,
@date='2020-06-18 22:56:08.367',
@usuario=N'admin'
```

**NOTE**: Generally, best practice is to, return the execution status of the procedure as return value. If you want to get some scalar value out of procedure execution, it is preferred to use output parameter and use them in subsequent stages.

```sql
DECLARE @p_Empl_ID int
DECLARE @legajo NVARCHAR(41)= N'USUARIO DE PRUEBA - Legajo: 1171'
EXEC EMPLEADOS_LEGAJOS @legajo, @p_Empl_ID OUTPUT
```